# VPS vs Dedicated

Tags: java, linux, process, vps, virtuozzo

Can I setup java based linux daemon on HostGator VPS? If yes than how? What will be the procedure (any help or detailed article)? HostGator provides virtuozzo as the OS  virtualization environment. I also want to know apart from virtuozzo how can I interact with the VPS to install, update applications and backend processes. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linux VPS looks exactly like a dedicated server, it just has fewer resources (the physical resources of the machine - RAM, HD etc) are shared between a number of virtual instances).

You can log in to your VPS using **ssh**, just as you would a dedicated server. You can then install, run, configure, hack whatever you like. Check with your provider (HostGator) for the IP address of your VPS and the root login details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I posted this question on stackoverflow and just got to know that it has been posted to serverfault. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the new Amazon "Micro Instances". IMHO it is the best of both worlds: http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/09/09/announcing-micro-instances-for-amazon-ec2/

Comment: I think Virtuozzo based VPS will be better for most users.  EC2 is too ephemeral.  They have a nice API but lots of stability issues.  For the same price you can get a much better VPS , virutozzo or openvz, which is a different virtualization technology than Xen.